# PHP JSON Array Multi Level

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I am stuck in a pickle trying to deal with a JSON Array Parse.

I have the need to take a JSON array and break the information out.

The JSON feed is as follows -

```
[
    {
        "ID": "344",
        "MaxOptions": 4,
        "MinOptions": 0,
        "ModifierGUID": "",
        "Name": "Remove Items",
        "Options": [
            {
                "DefaultOption": true,
                "Description": "",
                "ID": "68557",
                "MaxSelections": 99,
                "Name": "Remove Tomato ",
                "OptionGUID": "",
                "OptionItemID": "8e362d67-2a1e-4a31-9b54-48b19a147813",
                "PLU": "",
                "Price": 0.0000,
                "TakeawayPrice": 0
            },
            {
                "DefaultOption": true,
                "Description": "",
                "ID": "69254",
                "MaxSelections": 4,
                "Name": "Remove Cheese",
                "OptionGUID": "",
                "OptionItemID": "f1dbaaf5-be18-462b-8c7a-6207cb3deaf3",
                "PLU": "",
                "Price": 0.0000,
                "TakeawayPrice": 0
            }
           ]
        }
]
```

I have run the following code to decode the JSON initially

```
$json_url = ""; // INSIDE QUOTES THE JSON URL
$json_value = file_get_contents($json_url);
$array = json_decode($json_value,true);
foreach($array as $item) {
echo $item['ID']; // This Returns "344"
}
```

This is correct however I need to now run an additional foreach to get the array values within the "Options" section of the JSON but simply adding an additional foreach seems to not do as wanted!

I'm sure its going to be a simple fix BUT I cant seem to figure it out!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the exact issue that you are facing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! - the second foreach is displaying no results...

Comment: Can you post your code, how are you using the second foreach?

Comment: I had originally used `foreach($item['Options'] as $values) { ` however this didn't seem to work! its all sorted now though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
$json_url = ""; // INSIDE QUOTES THE JSON URL
$json_value = file_get_contents($json_url);
$array = json_decode($json_value,true);
foreach($array as $item) {
    echo $item['ID']; // This Returns "344"
    foreach($item['Options'] as $option) {
        //do the needed processing here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand properly, you can directly select Options by

```
$Options = $item['Options'];
```

please provide your expected output

EDIT: you might want this

```
$Options = array_column($array, 'Options');
```

this eliminates your foreach loop totally, remove foreach loop and add above line

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Ideally I need to break these options out into a foreach to run a process for each option listed.

Comment: Shubham that solved it I think I was going about the next for each incorrectly by using `foreach($item['Options'] as $values)` which didn't seem to work! all sorted now!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$array = json_decode($json_value,true);
$opt = $array['Options'];
foreach($opt as $item) {
    echo $item['ID'];
}
```